# Stored Procedure/SQL script that allows me to add a record to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 2 tables, one with all the email data, and another with all the specific member email data that one creates a row if an email has been read.
Once an email has been read by a member its added to the Member_email_read table (which is created and populated based on all read emails).

I am trying to set (on mass) all of the messages to read (this would populate the Member_email_read table) but whilst I can add them one at a time 
(see the stored procedue below), I am unable to add them on mass.

The two tables are Email, which holds a record for every email into the system. The other table is a table of all email that the member has read. Each time an email 
is read a record is added to the Member_email_read table. They are assiocited on the message_id (and both should use the same user_id). The two tables are as follows -

```
SELECT [member_email_id]
  ,[member_email_FK_message_id]
  ,[member_email_FK_user_id]
  ,[member_email_status]
  ,[member_email_read_datetime]
  ,[member_email_delete_datetime]
FROM [MemberData].[dbo].[Member_email_read]



SELECT[message_id]
  ,[email_catlogue_num]
  ,[email_FK_user_id]
  ,[Email_time]
  ,[email_content]
  ,[Email_created_date]
FROM [MemberData].[dbo].[Email]
```

To set all the messages (for a certain user) to unread all I would have to do is delete every record from that table for that user, which can be done with the following:

```
DELETE FROM [MemberData].[dbo].[Member_email_read]
WHERE [member_email_FK_message_id_FK_user_id] ='2';
```

I am basically looking for the reverse of this delete.

I have created a Stored procedure that allows for the setting of ONE specific email to be set to read, however this stored procedure (when executed) requires the member to enter a 
email_id, message_id, user_id, status, read_datetime & delete_datetime.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[set_member_email_to_read]

@member_email_id int,
@member_email_FK_message_id int,
@member_email_FK_user_id int
@member_email_status varchar(1),
@member_email_read_datetime dateTime,
@member_email_delete_datetime dateTime

as
if not exists (Select * from [dbo].[Member_email_read] where [member_email_FK_message_id] = @member_email_FK_message_id) begin
insert into [dbo].[Member_email_read]
    (
       [member_email_FK_message_id]
      ,[member_email_FK_user_id]
      ,[member_email_status]
      ,[member_email_read_datetime]
      ,[member_email_delete_datetime]
  )
  values
  (
        @member_email_FK_message_id,
        @member_email_FK_user_id
        @member_email_status,
        @member_email_read_datetime,
        @member_email_delete_datetime
  )


SELECT Convert(int,SCOPE_IDENTITY()) As InsertedID

end else begin
    update [dbo].[Member_email_read] set
   [member_email_FK_message_id]         =   @member_email_FK_message_id
  ,[member_email_FK_user_id]            =   @member_email_FK_user_id
  ,[member_email_status]                =   @member_email_status
  ,[member_email_read_datetime]         =   @member_email_read_datetime
  ,[member_email_delete_datetime]       =   @member_email_delete_datetime

where [member_email_FK_user_id] = @member_email_FK_user_id
if (@@ERROR = 0) begin
    SELECT Convert(int,@member_email_FK_user_id) As InsertedID
end
end
GO
```

I was hoping to create a stored procedure (or general SQL script) that would allow me to enter in 
a user_id and then allow for all emails for that user to change from unread to read (populate the Member_email_read table).

Comment: Have you considered triggers?

Comment: Is there a default `status` that you want? And is `email_read_datetime` the current timestamp, and `delete_datetime` to be `null`?

Comment: Not sure about using a trigger, not really used them before. How would it work in this instance?

Comment: The status can just be new or read the email_read_datetime & delete_datetime could be null - this has worked before

Comment: I don't think you need a trigger for this, but a `MERGE` statement should allow you to bulk insert/update to your read email table from your email table. Though, I question this table design. Why not just have a `read_datetime` field in the same email table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [`MERGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) to perform a bulk `insert`/`update` from your `Email` table into your `Member_email_read` table:

```
MERGE [MemberData].[dbo].[Member_email_read] AS tgt  
USING (
    SELECT message_id, user_id, 'R', null, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    FROM [MemberData].[dbo].[Email] 
    WHERE user_id = @UserId
) AS src (MessageId, UserId, Status, ReadDate, DeleteDate) 
ON (
    tgt.member_email_FK_message_id = src.message_id
    AND tgt.member_email_FK_user_id = src.user_id
)  
WHEN MATCHED THEN   
    UPDATE SET tgt.member_email_status = src.Status,
               tgt.member_email_read_datetime = src.ReadDate,
               tgt.member_email_delete_datetime = src.DeleteDate
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
    INSERT (member_email_FK_message_id, member_email_FK_user_id, 
            member_email_status, member_email_read_datetime, member_email_delete_datetime)  
    VALUES (src.MessageId, src.UserId, src.Status, src.ReadDate, src.DeleteDate)
;
```

This should work, though as I mentioned in my comment above, you should rethink your table design and simply add a `read_datetime` and `delete_datetime` (possibly a `status` column if you really need that as well) to your `Email` table, rather than having a whole separate table simply to hold records identifying a delete status.

Comment: Thanks @gmiley this solution worked well. I would change the architecture of the tables, however it is part of a large database that I inherited.

Comment: I have implemented the SQL script above and it mostly works well...however how would I ensure that the member_email_FK_message_id  (email table) is the same value as the message_id (member_email_read table) There seems to be duplicate records being created for different user_ids. I thought that as "tgt.member_email_FK_message_id = src.message_id" this would ensure that there was only 1 record and not duplicates. As a consequence not all emails are added and so not all are marked as unread......any ideas @gmiley?   Thanks

Comment: @Needabitofhelp This might be better as a new question, and I would be more than happy to help if you want to post it and give me the link. In a new post, provide the two table structures and sample data from both illustrating the issue that you are experiencing.

Comment: I have opened a new ticket on this question, it is posted here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942262/sql-merge-not-always-creating-a-row-for-a-member-email-read-table    @gmiley